# check if a div which is inserted by javascript has loaded

Tags: jquery

I have a page which loads in magento. Since i have to do some quick fix, I need to check if a DIV has loaded. The  is inserted using javascript.

div name: umm

using this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4160706/1147634

```
var len = jQuery('#umm').append('<a href="#">hi</a>')
    .find('a')
    .load(function() {
        if( --len === 0) {
            alert('all are loaded');
        }
    }).length;
```

HTML inserted using javascript.

```
<input id="evtproducttype" type="hidden" value="activities">
<input type="button" onclick="addInputGroup('evt_detail','evt_detaildhtmlgoodies_tabView1','evt_detailtabtitle');" value="+ Add Activity">
<div id="umm"></div>
<div id="dynamicGroupControl"></div>
```

I have to wait until this divs are loaded.

This doesn't work, and i my div is empty.

Comment: @Christoph why shouldnt that work ?!

Comment: @EvilP you need an element associated with an URL.

Comment: @EvilP its an empty div. With image its possible. But is it with empty one? Its not working while i checked.

Comment: @Christoph when you have a div that is placed on the website, you don't need anything to load content into it!

Comment: How is the DIV added to the page ? show us your code

Comment: @EvilP That is exactly what I was trying to say;)

Comment: @ManseUK Jleagle deleted the code for any reason.... BAD editing BAD boy !!

Comment: @umeshmoghariya I have added an answer - is this what you want ? your question is not very clear

Comment: @ManseUK Pls check code I have added. Letme know if its still not clear.

Comment: see the edit of my answer, this should be the solution for your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code looks a good starting point - but why not do this :

```
function addSomething() {
     $('#parentelement').append('<div>your contents</div>');
     // append is immediate - so you can now do your next step !
}
```

Things to note - the append function adds the element to a parent - so you need to select the correct parent. Once the append is complete you can do your next step. To call your addition just call the function `addSomething()`

### Updated

You have 2 options ....

Option 1  ... change your `onclick` :

```
onclick="addInputGroup('evt_detail','evt_detaildhtmlgoodies_tabView1','evt_detailtabtitle'); addSomething();"
```

this calls the `addSomething` function after your `addInputGroup` function

Option 2 ... Change your function :

```
function addInputGroup(arg1,arg2,arg3) {
  // do your normal stuff
  addSomething(); // or add the actual code here
}
```

The second option means its easier to modify every call to the function

### Updated again

The only real option you have is to actual call a function when your div is loaded ... you can use the [livequery plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/livequery) for that - this will trigger a function when the div is actually finished loading :

```
$('#umm').livequery(function(){ 
  // the div has not loaded
});
```

Comment: Thanks what i want to do. But I have to wait until the parent is div is loaded.

Comment: @umeshmoghariya updated my answer ... including your function `addInputGroup` would help if you need any further help

Comment: Hey thanks. But the thing I CANT change any of them. addInputGroup occurs when I click on the button to load a tab.[Cant wait till then] I need to load a MESSAGE when the page is loaded inside the div id='umm'. Also if this info helps, the page is coming after 2-3 worflow operations from Magento

Comment: I did not downvote you. I am rather surprised my self who did this.

Comment: @umeshmoghariya no probs ... does the updated answer meet your requirements ?

Comment: Ah, it looks like there is no longer `livequery` on the jquery site.

Answer (score 1):

The `load()` event only makes sense on elements associated with an URL (where a resource is loaded from). Since you cant use it on `div`or `a`, only  images, scripts, frames, iframes, and the `window` object.

The moment you add the `div` via js it is inserted into the dom-tree and "ready". YOu dont need to check that. That's only necessary for remote resources.

edit:

you need to wait with that call, until your document is ready (the dom-tree has been constructed)

Use either `$(document).ready( <yourcodehere> )` or directly `$( <yourcodehere> )` for that reason.

Comment: Did that the very first moment. DOM Elements loads way before the div. A javascript inserts the DIV in need to check for load. This js comes from another planet, and I was ASKED not to make any changes in that script.

Comment: well, that explains  everything. Your code executes before the external js had the chance to do it's work. Just add an if condition, checking frequently for the div like: if ( $("#umm").length == 1 ){do your stuff}.